# Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null Error, not sure why

Tags: javascript

Whenever I hover over the image it does not enlarge and gives an error.

HTML and Javascript code(these are two separate files):

```
var banner = document.getElementById("banner");

function enlargePic(){
banner.style.width = '800px';
banner.style.height  = '300px';
}

function normalPic(){
banner.style.width = '500px';
banner.style.height  = '200px';
}


banner.addEventListener("mouseover", enlargePic, false); 

banner.addEventListener("mouseout", normalPic, false); 

<div id="designs">
<a id="designs"></a>
<h1>DESIGNS.</h1> 
<table>
<tr>
<td><img src="banner2.jpg" id="banner"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: `banner` doesn't exist yet when you query it. Add the code **after** the markup, or in a document ready event.

Comment: What error? Elaborate.

Comment: What error is it giving you? Why do two elements have the same `id` in your HTML code? That is wrong!

Answer (score 5):

Your javascript code is in your first section. So it has rendered before banner element and cannot find the element id = banner because it has not rendered yet. Try to locate the code before the html code.

Answer (score 0):

When referencing the function normalpic, you should preceed it with an empty function:

```
banner.addEventListener("mouseout",function(){normalpic},false)
```